# Docker: docker-compose and migration

Tags: docker, migration, containers, export, docker-compose

I have a little question about migrating containers that are defined by a docker-compose file (I think that the docs are not very clear on this, except the part of the individual containers):

Suppose that you have a small project with a docker-compose file, and that you need to pass the current "containers stack snapshot" to a collegue (linked containers with actual volumes, not images), so that he can run the exact environment with the same "docker-compose start" command, how can you achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This is partially possible, but will need your input to achieve this. Why not have a script to do a backup on your setup, then on the other user’s side, create the structure and import data (this can be remote pull). In this way, everything will be identical.

Then only do mappings on the docker compose file, this runs after the initial script to setup the directory structure and data pull.